# trouble when editing json files and requests library in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

hi guys i'm trying to edit this json and change the "tempetura" and the "timestamp" sections but i'm stuck in it, and i need to send it to a server as well via http, and it's not accepting my json
here is the code:

```
    import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
    import requests
    import datetime
    import json



    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
        print("salvando mensagem...")
        temp = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
        data = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
        print("a mensagem recebida foi :" + temp)
        print("Mandando para o interscity...")

        payload = '{"data":{"environment_monitoring":[{"temperatura": "30.0","timestamp": "13/04/2020T109:29:00"}]}}'
        r = requests.post('address', json=payload, headers="content-Type: application/json")
        print("postado no interscity")

    subscribe.callback(on_message, "teste", hostname = "address", port=1883 )
```

edit1:

i fixed the json part, it had a list inside a library.

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
import requests
import datetime
import json



def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("salvando mensagem...")
    temp = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    data = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    print("a mensagem recebida foi :" + temp)
    print("Mandando para o interscity...")
    payload = '{"data":{"environment_monitoring":[{"temperatura": "30.0","timestamp": "13/04/2020T109:29:00"}]}}'
    y = json.loads(payload)
    y["data"]["environment_monitoring"][0]["temperatura"] = temp
    y["data"]["environment_monitoring"][0]["timestamp"] = data
    y = json.dumps(y)
    r = requests.post('server_addres', data=y, headers="content-Type: application/json")
    print("postado no interscity")

subscribe.callback(on_message, "teste", hostname = "mqtt_address", port=1883 )
```

Comment: OK there are two problems here, 1 you are sending a string to json when you should send a python data object (array or dict etc). If you want to send a string body use data=payload.

2 'address' likely will not resolve, this likely needs to be a variable or a fully qualified uri.

Comment: thank you for answering, i kinda figured out the json errors and the address is just not to disclose the address im sending because it has no security,but im still having trouble with the request library,
but my code now is like this, i`ll edit the code in the post